# #1050 - Table 'wp_commentmeta' already exists

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

Error
SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
  `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
  KEY `comment_id` (`comment_id`),
  KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191))
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
MySQL said: Documentation
```

> #1050 - Table 'wp_commentmeta' already exists

Comment: The error says that the table already exists. You want to delete existing table ande create new table? You want to change the structure of existing table?

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue and found that even if you drop the `wp_commentmeta` table, you are likely to have issues with other tables like `wp_comments`, `wp_links` etc.

Hence, the solution is just to drop the whole database, re-create a fresh one and restore to that. To do this, login to mysql:

```
mysql -u databaseuser -p
```

and then run the following command on your database:

```
drop database wordpress_database;
create database wordpress_database;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and had to drop all the tables. Not recommended for the faint of heart. Make sure you have at least two different types of backups.

Answer (score -1):

The error you are getting is pretty self explanatory!
You may **think** about executing the following SQL-Statement:

```
DROP TABLE wp_commentmeta;
```